# TeamCity says success but the msi doesn't load

Tags: testcomplete, teamcity-7.0

I'm running TeamCity agent(not as a service).I'm using command line to launch an application.if i save the command line in a *.cmd file and double click it the application is loading properly but if i copy ans paste the code from the cmd file to TeamCity and run... TeamCity says success but the application is not loading.if i run TeamCity as a service and click the run... it is loading the application but,along with it it is loading an "Interactive Services Detection"(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/04/27/what-is-interactive-services-detection-and-why-is-it-blinking-at-me.aspx)and that as i understood is not good so,i need to run it using the agent.bat file which is what i'm doing.
what can be the solution for this problem?

thanks

Comment: Can you post here the content of this CMD file?

Answer (score 0):

I got the agent service running by:

- opening Services (**cmd** => **services.msc**)
- right clicking on agent service (default is TeamCity Build Agent Service)
- Selecting the **Log On** tab
- Disabling 'Allow service to interact with desktop'